# Send multiple documents to multiple mail Id's

Tags: email

I have to send multiple documents to multiple mail id's on a single click. How do I do that? I don't know how that begin. Please help me find a solution

Comment: What language / API are you using? Are you actually trying to do that programmatically or are you asking about help with an email client?

Comment: I am trying to work that with php. I wanted to write a code that sends their salary slips to their respective mail id . By adding their id in the array list , and uploading the documents for pay slip,I want the mailer to send all at once. The employee id and the payslip document id are same